# how to open link of one web application (server 1) from another web applicaton (server2). Sigle sign on Problem

Tags: asp.net

Guys,
 I have made two web application, both application deployed on differnent server with database. one have SQL and other Oracle.

server 1: Web application 1/SQL Database.
Server 2: Web Application 2/Oracle Database.

I have given link of Web application 2 on web Application 1. its means single sign on logic. I have login in web application 1 and click link of web application 2, when I click on link I want to authenticate to user in oracle databse (on server 2) if user is valid or not.

Please help how could do this.

its urgent.

Answer (score 0):

You can think an [httpwebrequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) to the other site.

On the other site you request the data that you wish for on a regular page and you send it to the first that just show it.

For the security, you need to think ether an ssl connection and exchange some login data, or just say that this page can only accept data from that computer, or what ever...

```
HttpWebRequest myReq =
(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.secondserver.com/data.aspx?dataid=23321");
```